# Preventing automatic change of default-directory

Tags: emacs

As per [the Emacs docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Names.html), every time you open a file, Emacs changes `default-directory` to the directory containing that file.

Then, if the cursor is in that buffer and you (for example) start SLIME, it uses `default-directory` as the current working directory for SLIME.  If you try to open a new file, it opens the file with `default-directory` as your starting point.

I want to be able to `M-x cd` or otherwise `cd` to a directory, and then never have Emacs change my current working directory to anything but that directory until I tell it otherwise.  I want this to be global across all buffers, so that any time I'm doing something involving the current working directory, I know what it's set to regardless of where my cursor is at the moment.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try using something like this:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq default-directory command-line-default-directory)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another variant is to bind *default-directory* to the necessary directory in directory-local variables, e.g. in the .dir-locals.el file in one of your parent directories to something like:

```
((nil . ((default-directory . "~/.emacs.d/"))))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the best I've come up with so far, sadly:

```
(defun find-file-save-directory ()
    (interactive)
    (setq saved-default-directory default-directory)
    (ido-find-file)
    (setq default-directory saved-default-directory))
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-f" 'find-file-save-directory)
```

This works as long as `default-directory` is properly set before I `C-x C-f`.  I'm going to Accept jurta's answer for pointing me in a useful direction.