# Change the default directory of emacs with 'cocoa emacs'

Tags: macos, emacs

As explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464/changing-the-default-folder-in-emacs), putting (setq default-directory "~/Desktop/mag" ) in .emacs is supposed to change the default directory.

When I do that with the emacs on my mac, it doesn't work. C-x C-f still shows ~/ not ~/Desktop/mag.

(cd "Users/smcho/Desktop/mag") also gives me this error - Error: No such directory found via CDPATH environment variable

What's wrong with them?

Comment: Is it possible you need a / at the front of the path in the `(cd "/Users/smcho/Desktop/mag")`?  (No mac at my fingertips to check).  Though I don't think this will have the effect you really want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The directory that appears in the prompt for C-x C-f ('find-file') comes from the value of default-directory, which is a buffer-local variable. When you first start Emacs, the initial buffer displayed is the *GNU Emacs* buffer.  That buffer's default-directory is set from the variable command-line-default-directory.

So, try this:

```
(setq command-line-default-directory "~/Desktop/mag")
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  But Trey's does.  Actually I thought there was a simpler version than what he proposed.

Comment: @Jim Blandy: Your explanation was perfect. I was wondering why `(cd <my-path>)` didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The straight-forward answer to your question is:

```
(setq-default default-directory "~/Desktop/mag")
```

Reading the documentation for the variable (<kbd>C-h v default-directory RET</kbd>) you'll see:

> Automatically becomes buffer-local
>   when set in any fashion.   This
>   variable is safe as a file local
>   variable if its value   satisfies the
>   predicate `stringp'.

That said, opening a file automatically sets the `default-directory` to the path of the file...

So, if you always want `find-file` to start at that directory, you can use this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'my-find-file)
(defun my-find-file ()
  "force a starting path"
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory "~/scratch/"))
    (call-interactively 'find-file)))
```

This question may be a duplicate of [Preventing automatic change of default-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354490/preventing-automatic-change-of-default-directory).  Though it's difficult to tell.

Comment: I added the code in .emacs, but C-c C-f shows me the ~/ not ~/Desktop/mag.

Comment: @prosseek You *always* want `C-c C-f` to start at `~/Desktop/mag`?  That's slightly different, and I think already answered.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. C-x C-f was the key what I intended to use to open "~/Desktop/mag", but it's OK that I find a way to open it using C-c C-f.

Comment: @prosseek - I'd wondered if it was `C-x C-f`, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the notes above regarding `default-directory`, I had to also prevent the emacs splash screen from starting in order to make subsequent commands like `dired` actually show their buffer when invoked from `.emacs` on startup:

```
   (setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
```