# How to check if a variable is set to what in elisp/emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Let's say I have the following line in .emacs file.

```
(setq-default default-directory "~/Desktop/mag")
```

How can I check the value for `default-directory' in elisp?

### Added

I asked this question as I need to check the value of default-directory based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364221/change-the-default-directory-of-emacs-with-cocoa-emacs).

The elisp code should change the default directory when I click C-x C-f, but I still get ~/, not ~/Desktop/mag. So, I need to check what value the default-directory has.

Comment: Could you clarify your question please?  Clearly "just evaluate `default-directory`" is not the answer you want, so what does that not do that you need?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you just want to check the value, you can run the following from the *scratch* buffer:

```
(print default-directory) <ctrl-j>
```

The *scratch* buffer allows you to evaluate lisp on the fly. You must hit ctrl-j after to evaluate.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but I think my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20255760/1050454) is better. It is faster not having to switch buffer. Also, aren't some variables buffer-local?

Comment: Aha, the OP wants it **in Elisp**. Sorry, then the above doesn't apply.

Answer (score 27):

If you're at the console you can type C-h v, which will prompt you for a variable name. Type in default-directory (or any other name) and you'll get a buffer with some info about that variable, including its value.

The elisp function you're running is describe-variable:

```
(describe-variable VARIABLE)
```

I figured this out by C-h k C-h v. C-h k shows you what function the next key or key sequence would call.

Comment: To combine Paul and monotux's answers : The sure/fast way to check if your var is set is to position the point over it and press `C-h v` : If your var is auto-selected by eldoc for info, then it IS set. Uber-handy indeed.

Comment: [Documented in the GNU Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/See-variable-current-value.html) and bound to `C-h v`.

Answer (score 8):

As previously stated, `C-h v` is the easiest way to find out a variables value. To make it even better, place your cursor on the variable you want to know about, and then run `C-h v`, and it will default to the word under the cursor. Really handy.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(print default-directory)
```

write the above code in one line inside of emacs, got to the end of the line and hit `C-x C-e`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the variable value in the echo
area (less of a mess), try:

```
(defun describe-variable-short (var)
  (interactive "vVariable: ")
  (message (format "%s: %s" (symbol-name var) (symbol-value var))) )
(global-set-key "\C-hV" 'describe-variable-short)
```

Comment: Or just type `M-: name RET` (for the variable name in question)